# Making a JSON of two dataframes leads to output with backslashes

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I want to combine in order to make a JSON:

```
data1 = {"J&V": ["base", "mutation", "structural"], 
         "2022": [500, 100, 'False'], 
         "2023": [1400, 200, 'False'], "2024": [1200, 50, 'False']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2 = {"Name": ["FirstMutation", "SecondMutation", "ThirdMutation"], 
         "2022": [50, 50, 0], "2023": [50, 50, 100], 
         "2024": [0, 50, 0]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Where the data of the second dataframe add up to the the second row of the first dataframe.

Now, I  am trying to create a JSON file by combining them. Note that I import df1 and df2 by using pd.read_excel().

```
import pandas as pd
import json 

path = "path"


# import df1 using read_excel()
df = pd.read_excel(path, index_col =0 )
text = df.to_json(orient='columns')
print(text)
expenses = []
expenses.append(text)
names = []
names.append("J&V")
measures = []
print(text)

# import df2 using read_excel()
df_m = pd.read_excel(path, index_col= 0, sheet_name="JV_M")
df_dict = df_m.to_dict(orient='index')

values = []
for i in df_dict.values():
    print(type(i))
    print(i)
    s = json.dumps(i)
    values.append(s)

df_m['DictYears'] = values
df_combined = df_m[['DictYears']]
df_combined['Names2'] = df_combined.index
df= df_combined[['Names2', 'DictYears']]
text = df.to_json(orient='records')
measures.append(text)
parsed = json.loads(text)
print(text)
print(parsed)

df_hfdst = pd.DataFrame({"Expenses": expenses, "Measures" : measures}, index= names)
df_hfdst.index.rename("Name", inplace=True)
df_hfdst['Names'] = df_hfdst.index

df = df_hfdst[['Names', 'Expenses', 'Measures']]

text = df_hfdst.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')
text = df.to_json(orient='records')
parsed = json.loads(text)
print(parsed)
print(text)
```

This gives the following output:

`[{"Names":"J&V","Expenses":"{\"2022\":{\"Base\":500,\"Mutation\":100,\"Structural\":\"False\"},\"2023\":{\"Base\":1400,\"Mutation\":200,\"Structural\":\"False\"},\"2024\":{\"Base\":1200,\"Mutation\":50,\"Structural\":\"False\"},\"Struc\":{\"Base\":null,\"Mutation\":10,\"Structural\":\"True\"}}","Measures":"[{\"Names2\":\"FirstMutation\",\"DictYears\":\"{\\\"2022\\\": 50, \\\"2023\\\": 50, \\\"2024\\\": 0}\"},{\"Names2\":\"SecondMutation\",\"DictYears\":\"{\\\"2022\\\": 50, \\\"2023\\\": 50, \\\"2024\\\": 50}\"},{\"Names2\":\"ThirdMutation\",\"DictYears\":\"{\\\"2022\\\": 0, \\\"2023\\\": 100, \\\"2024\\\": 0}\"}]"}]`

Clearly something is wrong as it gives additional backslashes. I am pretty sure that this is also not the most straightforward method to produce a JSON file, but what may the cause be of these backslashes?

Comment: what is the relation between `df1`, `df2`  and your code ?

Comment: I have them both as an Excel file and import them using pd.read_excel().  I added them separately as a dataframe in order to clarify it a bit.